# Within PHP should I use today's date function or curdate() from MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm writing a `PHP/MySQL` program. I need to add the current date each time a new record to the `TABLE` is added. I have a field called `DATE_ADDED`. I'm confused how to use `CURDATE()` function from `MySQL` to write this to the TABLE. Or should I from `PHP` use a date function to get today's date and pass it as a variable to be written to the TABLE? I don't need a `TIMESTAMP`, just `YYYY-MM-DD`.
Thanks!

Comment: change the column in the database to TIMESTAMP and make it auto insertable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to try with php like

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
```

and then while adding data to your db give this value with the remaining

Comment: I agree Gautam, doing with PHP is faster and easy.

Comment: What if PHP and MySQL are on different time zones?

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO table_name ( field1, field2,...DATE_ADDED )
                   VALUES
                   ( value1, value2,...CURDATE());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set it as the default value for that column `date_added` in the table definition like so:

```
date_added TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can I use DATE instead of TIMESTAMP since I only want YYYY-MM-DD?

Comment: @Edward You can ignore the time part and get only the date something like `DATE(date_added)`, but the problem is that if you want to set it as the default value you can't use `CURDATE` that's why I used `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and it is the standard ANSI function to get the current date.

Answer (score 1):

```
$regdate=date('Y-m-d');
$sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (fld_name1, fld_name2,fld_regdate) VALUES ('value1', 'value2', '$regdate')";
$rs = mysql_query($sql) or die('ERROR:' mysql_error());
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO joke SET     
       joketext = :joketext,     
       jokedate =  CURDATE()'; 
    $s = $pdo->prepare($sql); 
    $s->bindValue(':joketext', $_POST['joketext']); 
    $s->execute();
```